# Consistent way to tell when Instant Play movies will expire in Netflix

Tags: netflix

I've noticed there's a discrepancy between the web view of my Instant Play queue and the XBox 360 view of it.  In the XBox view if a movie will be expiring on a specific date, I see the warning when I first bring up the movie in the list.  Granted it goes away after a couple seconds, but I still can see that the movie will be unavailable soon.  When I look at the exact same list in the web view I don't see that warning.  I'm fairly certain I used to be able to see that warning in the web view, but it seems awhile ago it disappeared.  Is there a setting that I may have inadvertently changed, or is there a way to see that warning again?  Perhaps a web service that is similar to [Feed Flix](http://feedfliks.com) in analyzing a user's queues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apparently never bothered to actually look closely at the dashboard page of Feed Flix or navigate beyond it.  Feed Flix actually shows the expiration date of movies in the Instant Watch queue.  The dashboard was incorrectly telling me that I had a couple that would expire within 2 weeks, but it might be because I have some that are currently expired still in the queue.